# Garbage collection question

Tags: java, c++, actionscript-3, garbage-collection

Consider the following segment of code:

```
function loadSomeContent()
{
    URLLoader loader = new URLLoader("http://www.somesite.com/");

    loader.addEventListner("onLoadComplete", loadCompleteHandler);

    loader.sendHttpRequest();
}

function loadCompleteHandler(event)
{
    log("Load response received");
}
```

Do not worry about the syntax of this code.

Here is my concern - The loader object which is used to send the HTTP request and which has the *onLoadComplete* event registered to is not referenced from outside the *loadSomeContent()* function. Is there a possibility that the loader object will be garbage collected and *loadCompleteHandler()* will never be called?

Comment: Why is the tagged with C++, Java, and OOP?

Comment: removed oop; added garbage-collection.  Didn't touch the other language tags since I can't figure out whether they belong or not.

Comment: The reason oop, c++ and Java are there is because I wanted to keep the question generic to these oop languages and not limited to as3. That is also the reason I ask the reader to not worry about the syntax.

Comment: I don't think you can have a *generic answer* for this. This seems very implementation-dependent, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `loader.sendHttpRequest()` a new thread is created that will actually send the request in the background.  This thread keeps a reference to the loader so that it can call the load complete function when the load is finished.  As a result the loader will always be referenced by some thread, just not the thread you're in right now.

Comment: So, would this be language specific or every language which supports asynchronous events does this by creating a new thread?

Comment: Not necessarily actually creating a new thread, but whatever mechanism is in place for achieving deferred execution needs to have some way of holding references to the things it is supposed to execute!  How would it execute them later otherwise?

Comment: From experience, I tend to agree with you that the loader won't be collected while it's active in practice. But this behavior is not documented in any spec (to my knowledge at least). So, I'd say, don't rely on this. There's another object in the net API, namely `FileReference`, that is definitely collectable if you don't pin it down (even if you've started the download)

Comment: I would call that a bug in the API.  If an object chooses to defer its actions to a later time than either that object should be responsible for maintaining its lifecycle or that fact should be clearly documented in the API.

Answer (score 1):

No. Not as long as the URLLoader contains a callback that is still referenced somewhere (in this case, it's still referenced by the Javascript Engine/JVM/whatever because the Engine has to call it later.

Comment: I'm afraid this reflects a common misconception about callbacks and listeners. Adding a listener does not prevent the dispatcher from being collected per se. The callback function/closure is not the point here. The fact that the loader is active prevents it from being collection, based on observation, but to me knowledge this is not documented behavior, so it could change in future releases. I think you're better off storing a non-local reference to the loader while it's in use.

Comment: @Juan: No, that's wrong. Things that are in the stack of a thread or can be reached from at least one entry in the stack don't get collected. Look at a java program - everything running is "just" a thread.

Comment: I disagree. From an actionscript point of view, the loader is not reachable. Of course it's alive and reachable by the player, but that's an internal implementation detail. In the case of a loader, while it's active, it doesn't get collected. That's a special case (running timers are another one), and an "abstraction leak", so to speak. But the callbacks are not preventing the loader from being collected. Don't take my word on this, try it yourself. Add all the callbacks you want to the loader. At the same time, have a function that at a given interval calls System.gc.

Comment: (cont) You'll see that your loader will get collected eventually, whether you remove the callbacks or not. If you started the load operation, it will be collectable when this operation finishes (or fails). Again, this is because the loader is active, not because you added listeners to it. On the other hand, if you don't call load(), the loader is collectable right away (despite the event listeners)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, an active loader object such as `URLLoader` or `Loader` won't be collected (while it's active).

However, an important point that shouldn't be missed is that this an observable behavior, at best, but it's not documented as such (at least, to my knowledge; I might be wrong).

So, despite the internal mechanism used by the player to implement this (whether it creates a new thread, uses a centralized and global connection pool, etc, etc), I think you should not rely on this, because you'd be tying your code to an implementation detail (again, if this behavior is documented, this does not apply!).

Also, as I mentioned in a comment, there's a class in the `flash.net` API, `FileReference` that could be collected if you used it as in your code.

So, to sum it up: you can probably get away with just storing a local reference based on how things currently work (and based on observation!) but this is not guaranteed, so you're better off storing a non-local reference while your loader is active.

Answer (score 0):

only if:

```
function loadCompleteHandler(e: event): void{
    (e.target as URLLoader).removeEventListner("onLoadComplete", loadCompleteHandler);
}
```

it should be collected by AS3 GC (so that there are no references left and so we can't check if this local var exists:)

Comment: @www0z0k. Sorry, but this is wrong. The *loader* has a reference to the handler (and indirectly to the object where the handler is defined). That means the handler scope is reachable from the loader, but not the other way around (reachable from Actionscript code, anyway). So removing the handler doesn't affect the "collectability" of the *loader* (though it might affect the reachability of handler scope).

Comment: @Juan Pablo Califano: AFAIK a local variable is an instance created inside the function and will be killed after the function is invoked or after it completes current action(if any). It won't be killed only if it's referenced in any way: added to array or has a handler. The handler scope is unreachable from the caller, but the caller is passed to a handler as an event.target(so while an instance has handlers it's referenced). Local var URLLoader with no handlers performs load (HTTPFox shows it), but i don't have a tool for reading RAM to check when it's killed.

Comment: @www0z0k. "so while an instance has handlers it's referenced". No, that's my point. If you do `loader.addEventListener("someEvent",someHandler)` in a class instance, `this` will be referenced by `loader`. But if `loader` is a local variable, `this` doesn't have a reference to `loader`. So the handler will not prevent (at least, not by itself) `loader` from being collected. If you add `loader` to an instance-scoped `array`, as you mention, then yes, loader will be reacheable (because `array` is reachable and it has a reference to the `loader`, which makes the loader object reachable).

Comment: @Juan Pablo Califano: "if loader is a local variable, this doesn't have a reference to loader. So the handler will not prevent (at least, not by itself) loader from being collected" if a loader has listeners - it means that it stores references to listener functions so it can't be collected because there are entities that are waiting until it fires some event(s). I tried to check if anonimous listeners block GC but failed because i don't know how to check is a local variable or anonimous function alive or not. do you know any helpful tools?

Comment: @www0z0k. Sorry to insist, but this is the point where you are wrong: " if a loader has listeners - it means that it stores references to listener functions so it can't be collected because there are entities that are waiting until it fires some event(s)". It definitely can be collected. A good tool for monitoring objects is Flex Builder's profiler. Another technique is using weak-ref dictionaries (as outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793283/perplexing-garbage-collection-issue/3795415#3795415).

Comment: (cont...) By the way you can try the code in the answer I mentioned, add a listener and see it gets collected (as long as the loader isn't active). Whether the loader has listeners or not doesn't change this.

Answer (score 0):

in actionscript the loader will not get garbage collected.  The event handler is still registered as a link since you didn't add a weak reference to it.  I actually do this quite often for loading, I like it since you don't have to store arrays of objects to deal with references.

This would break if you add a weak reference:

```
loader.addEventListner("onLoadComplete", loadCompleteHandler, false, 0, true);
```

You may have memory issues if you don't clean your reference in the loadCompleteHandler;

```
function loadCompleteHandler(event) {
    (event.currentTarget as URLLoader).removeEventListener('onLoadComplete');
}
```